# Finding all characters till it finds the FIRST occurrence of a string given and then keep fetching the rest with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

```
$HTML = '

<div class="tsts">CONTENT GOES HERE 1ENDENDENDENDEND<div class="tsts">CONTENT GOES HERE 2ENDENDENDENDEND <div class="tsts">CONTENT GOES HERE 3ENDENDENDENDEND
<div class="tsts">CONTENT GOES HERE 4ENDENDENDENDEND

';

preg_match_all('%<div class="tsts">([\S\s]+)ENDENDENDENDEND%',$HTML,$matches);
```

I want it to find "CONTENT GOES HERE 1", "CONTENT GOES HERE 2", "CONTENT GOES HERE 3", "CONTENT GOES HERE 4" in the matches

By the way I MUST use \s\S because I need to match all kind of characters including special characters, new lines, tabs , but I want it to stop when it finds the ENDENDENDENDEND and get the other results

how do I do this? because its only stopping in the last occurence of ENDENDENDENDEND, and I want it to stop in the first one that it finds. so it can match the rest.

How do I do this? I tried so much and nothing =X.
Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have php environment, however the point is the express isn't it? see the grep test:

```
kent$  echo "'

<div class="tsts">CONTENT GOES HERE 1ENDENDENDENDEND<div class="tsts">CONTENT GOES HERE 2ENDENDENDENDEND <div class="tsts">CONTENT GOES HERE 3ENDENDENDENDEND
<div class="tsts">CONTENT GOES HERE 4ENDENDENDENDEND

'; 

"|grep -Po "(?<=<div class="tsts">)([\s\S]*?)(?=ENDENDENDENDEND)"     

CONTENT GOES HERE 1
CONTENT GOES HERE 2
CONTENT GOES HERE 3
CONTENT GOES HERE 4
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed. :) I have got to remember to use the lookahead, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to use `\s\S` for that. And the `+` quantifier is likely the second problem here.

The normal `.*?` will do, if you don't forget the `/s` flag.
In your case a `[^<>]*?` might be even better, because you don't want to match tag delimiters.